# RESTapi object retrieval

Tags: php, android, oop, laravel

I have a very "weird" problem, I guess you can also call it specific.

Here's what I'm trying to do, here's a very simplified version of my db:

```
+ORDERS
  id
  table_id

+TABLES
  id
  number
  seats
```

So, let's say I want to fetch my orders from an android Application, I thought of using a JSON to do so (I'm parsing them with retrofit; which uses Gson). Here's how it would look.

{id: '1', table:{id:1, number: 1, seats: 3}}

In my app, I get an object like this

```
Public Order{

private int id;
private Table table;

}
```

Great! right?. Well, not quite... the thing is. I don't want to fetch the table every time I fetch the order, because the tables is always the same, it does not change. I want to fetch all tables when the user logs in, save them in a SQLite DB, and then just bring the table ID when fetching the orders (that would reduce the size of my JSON and speed up my queries).

So, this is how my JSON looks now.

```
{id: '1', table:1}
```

but now, here how my POJO looks:

```
Public Order{

private int id;
private int table_id;

}
```

That's not very "OOP-ish" :/ I cannot do things like myOrder.getTable(). So, that's my predicament. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is better then second because:

in your first approach:

1.**One Http request**

if you get table data in json string then it will not cause much impact on performance as your table data is coming as a string in your response.

But in your second approach:

1.**One Http request**

2.**One Sqlite request**(Sqlite query will also impact your performance)

Comment: Well, I have to keep a lot of orders on my APP, I will eventually end up inserting them into a SQLite DB (I don't think it's wise to have them on a static variable hogging up the device RAM). Also keep in mind that the table information does not change, so I would be getting the number of seats multiple times (this is a reduced version I also have a table description, location etc etc) It seems very redundant

Comment: you have resolve any redundancy at database end you don't need to store table in local database..It will cause performance impact and also problem in future like if user clear application data then your tables will be lost.

Comment: I think I'm not following you... If I don't store my Order objects into a db, how do gain future access to them. I was thinking of saving them on a static variable, but that might cause problems (and doesn't sound like good practice)

Comment: According to your query each order have a specific table,So tables are different for each order.

Comment: Well, I have a finite number of tables. Each one is different, but why would I bring the whole table when I can just bring its ID and then link it on my app (not sure if I can do this :P )